# How can I own an IP address?

Tags: ip

How can I own an IP address like I do with domains?

I have done some research and it seems that you can't buy a single IP, but rather you have to purchase a range of IP addresses.

**Update : Important Note**
I want this IP to use it with my servers. for example I had a VPS, it went bad, I want to be able to use the same IP on another VPS from another company.

Comment: In short: You can. Check sxtnc's answer.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Posted an answer. :)

Comment: Just note that you can't get an IPv4 address anymore by yourself (they're all allocated as of a few months ago), you'll need to get it from an ISP or VPS/web host who already has it.  You *can*, however, reserve IPv6 addresses (we have trillions to go).

Comment: The reason we have domains is so that you don't have to own an IP.

Comment: I need a subnet for the same reason. I cannot use domains for dns server orr layer 3 router

Answer (score 55, accepted):

What you want just isn't possible on a small scale.

IP Addresses are purchased in blocks by companies with a hell of a lot of money and more importantly, infrastructure. When you get one, unless you are going direct to your [RIR (Regional Internet Registry)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_Registry), you are only renting the IP.

Even if you then owned an IP by going direct to your RIR (which can be very expensive just to register... See [ARIN](https://www.arin.net/fees/fee_schedule.html), [RIPE](http://www.ripe.net/lir-services/member-support/become-a-member/membership-fees)), I highly doubt any VPS provider will add a route to your IP as it will require a significant change to their own infrastructure.

The best thing you can do is to use a single provider that specialises in uptime/100% availability, it will be expensive, but, this is by far the cheapest way of going around it.

---

### I'm updating this answer significantly as I have received so many emails asking for more info or help and approximate costs...

What you are asking for is hard and expensive. For just two VPS from a provider - I highly doubt you will find anyone willing due to complexity... But if someone does want to go down this route, it isn't impossible.

To understand routing across the internet, you need to know that there is more than IP routing alone. BGP is a routing protocol used by providers in order for them to say "My ips are here". To participate in BGP, you need an AS number, and to get an AS number and IPs, you need to register with a RIR (as explained above).

When participating in BGP, instead of buying internet as a service from a provider, you buy IP transit from a provider which allows you to publish your AS number/IPs

So, you would have IP transit at multiple locations and you would then publish BGP routes from one, and if connectivity to one site fails, you publish the route to the other location and ips are routed there.

As for price, you will need to find a colocation package that allows you to have IP transit... If you shop around, minimum would probably be £300 a month for a quarter rack.

Next, the transit itself - around £5-£10 per Mb of IP transit when purchased at low totals.

I am not sure on all RIR fees as they all have different prices and structures (e.g. ARIN pay for how many IP blocks you have, starting at $500 for a /24 with a max price of $32,000, where as ripe is €1,800 for unlimited).

Lastly, you will need a server (any price!) and a router capable of BGP.

After you have done this, duplicate it, or even triplicate it! (Other than the RIR fees, that's a one off!).

And if you can't follow this, I'm always up for consultation ;)

Comment: do you mean to buy 1 IP address it cost 5k USD?

Comment: @Pacerier - I never mentioned a cost other than being expensive... You need to register to the authority in question before you even buy one IP, you get them by the block, but, price is a very complicated matter.

Comment: Assuming you live in the US, it looks like the very least you'll pay is USD500 per year for a /22 (v4) or /40 (v6) block. See the [ARIN fee schedule](https://www.arin.net/fees/fee_schedule.html).

As the annual fee implies, you can only reserve a block; one cannot own addressable space.

Comment: What exactly is a 'block'? Is it the same as a 'range'? Can it be any size? Is it something like 1.2.3.x (= 255 IPs)?

Comment: @WilliamHilsum Maybe you should update your answer, as it is not that impossible nowadays, AWS allows you to bring your own IPs (BYOIP) (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-byoip.html)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are somewhere in the geographic area covered by ARIN, [this tells you what you need to do](https://www.arin.net/resources/request.html).  Generally you need to be an ISP of some sort.  You probably want to [apply for an AS number](https://www.arin.net/resources/request/asn.html) as well since if you are an ISP you need it for your BGP routing.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy blocks of numbers from [Addrex](http://addrex.net) they really know their stuff. The RIRs are leasing numbers now. If you get IPs from your ISP you are renting. If you are on a hosting service you are not going to be able to purchase numbers that can port or take with you. The RIRs are pretty much out of space so the secondary market is your best bet. Companies like ARIN still require needs assessment and are designed for ISPs more than small companies or application providers.

Comment: It appears that the question is about purchasing a single IP address and not a range.

Answer (score 2):

I would have a read here: http://www.ripe.net/lir-services/resource-management/faq/faq-general-resources

The best thing, if you don't need a huuuge net - is to get dedicated IP-adresses from your ISP. I know many provides pretty large nets, if needed.

Edit: I believe the question has been edited.. But the comments are correct!

To own them I would go for a Provider Independent network, and get the ISP in question to route.

Comment: Dedicated IP is not ISP transferable...

Comment: @BloodPhilia, Dedicated IP is not owned by you.......

Comment: URL in this answer is dead now

Comment: @Penguin9 - You are correct sir. It seems like some information is still available at: https://www.ripe.net/participate/member-support/become-a-member

Answer (score 2):

Now that is NOT possible. Different ISPs, providers, can provide different IP blocks.
What you need, is a domain address. That you can point to your VPS's IP all the time, no matter how many times you change your provider.

Comment: you see, my problem is I have to connect to various servers which need IP authentication. if I change the IP address, I have to recheck with them and every time it takes around a week to be confirmed.

Comment: The only solution for that is having a _good_ VPS provider which gives you a reliable VPS. That's all. OR you can tunnel your traffic through a static IP ...vps, shell, whatsoever ... every time you connect to such a "static IP authenticated" host.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @William Hilsum and @ultrasawblade, you must spent a considerable amount of money and effort to own and operate and IP address range. You will become a quite decent ISP if you actually have such infrastructure.

However, you don't actually need to **own** an IP address to achieve what you want. All you need is the right to **use** a fixed IP address. You might be able to get one from an ISP, cloud service or co-location provider and ask them "route" it to your actual IP through VPN or address translation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible solution. Just set up a cron job/bash script to constantly take note of your servers current public IP address. If it changes, make the script change your IP on the DNS Server (which you should also be hosting if you're doing this). This way, you don't actually need a static IP address.

Also, let me know if you try this.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @Juno Sprite, I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for feedback. It's a 10 year old thread, and the OP has posted nothing since 2013... :-D

Comment: This is called "dynamic DNS" and many DNS servers support it in some flavor; you won't have to run your own DNS server.  (And can't, because the DNS server itself needs a known fixed IP, in order to be authoritative for a domain)

Comment: @Peregrino69 well the OP is still alive and well :D but the actual problem no longer stands.

Comment: @2hamed I'm glad to hear that - please pass my best regards to the OP :-D