# How can I purchase an IPV6 address?

Tags: ipv6

Is is now possible to purchase either a single IPV6 address or blocks of them considering how many there are available?

I've come across a few questions on here but most of them from what I can see are referring to IPV4 addresses such as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/323801/how-can-i-own-an-ip-address) one.

Comment: https://www.arin.net/resources/request/ipv6_initial_assign.html

Comment: Its not cheap either https://www.arin.net/fees/fee_schedule.html

Comment: Your ISP can also give you some of their address block at no charge.

Comment: From the sounds of it my ISP isn't switching over any time soon, this is why I was hoping I could purchase a block and hopefully switch over to my own IPV6 address, probably not going to happen after seeing the fees. If you want to write that up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: By "ISP", he means whoever you're going to get IPv6 service from, not necessarily whoever you get IPv4 service from.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz a majority of ISPs in Aus aren't switching. Doesn't matter who I go with and as far as I know only an ISP can give out an IP address, correct?

Comment: Even if you were to acquire a block, you wouldn’t be able to use it. Simply use a tunnel provider.

Comment: @XO The ISP you get IPv6 service from doesn't have to be the same as the ISP you get IPv4 service from. For example, you can use [Hurricane Electric](https://www.tunnelbroker.net/) as your IPv6 provider. (They'll give you a /48 for free. You just need a static, pingable IPv4 address for the tunnel endpoint.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I didn't know that, should I just close this question or leave it open for someone to answer?

Comment: You could also get a VPS and set it up to route traffic, e.g. with OpenVPN or SSH.

Comment: I've read that getting addresses directly from your ISP can be a pain if you ever change ISPs, as now all of your IPv6 addresses change. It was recommended to get them from ARIN instead, but I see that they only do this if you expect to use at least 2000 addresses or require 200 /64 subnets. Is it possible to buy a single /48 that's not tied your ISP or routed through a tunnel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply for a [block of addresses from Arin](https://www.arin.net/resources/request/ipv6_initial_assign.html)

[But they are not cheap](https://www.arin.net/fees/fee_schedule.html)

Your Internet Service Provider can give you some for free. if they use IPv6 that is.

Comment: This is really not the right answer unless you are an ISP or LIR.

Comment: The question was simple, "How can I buy", they did not specify any parameters or who they were.

Comment: @Moab It could be inferred that they couldn't possibly qualify from the fact that they inquired about a single IPv6 address.

Answer (score 12):

You don't have to buy IPv6 addresses. There are so many, they have no individual value. They are given away for free in blocks as large as 2^80 (over 1.2 septillion) at a time (a /48 from Hurricane Electric's tunnelbroker.net).

If your ISP supports IPv6, they will automatically assign you at least 2^64 addresses, which is the minimum for a single LAN (really!).

If your ISP does not support IPv6, you can tunnel IPv6 over your IPv4 ISP to a free service like tunnelbroker.net.

Comment: internode in Australia provides 2^56. Over 72 quadrillion for each customer.